# IEx - How to cancel multiline command?

Tags: elixir

When I use IEx and make a typo like additional bracket or ", then most of the time I get a syntax error. But there are cases like this one:

```
iex(3)> Enum.each '12345', &(IO.puts(&1"))    
...(3)> end   
...(3)> )   
...(3)> '    
...(3)> end    
...(3)> ""    
...(3)> ... ? How to produce syntax error ?    
...(3)>     
BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded    
      (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
```

I cannot make a syntax error and continue from scratch and I have to relaunch entire IEx.
Is there any keyboard shortcut or command to skip performing current iex(3) and go to next iex(4)?

Comment: the solutions to this are pretty annoying, I wished they included an option in the `BREAK` menu to cancel current multiline command, or make the first ctrl-c cancel it...

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Start your line with `#iex:break`

```
iex(1)> Enum.each '12345', &(IO.puts(&1"))    
...(1)> ...
...(1)> #iex:break

** (TokenMissingError) iex:1: incomplete expression
```

Comment: This is mentioned in the documentation, in the section "Expressions in IEx" (before the functions documentation begins): http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/iex/IEx.html

Comment: and how does one interrupt a long running command and cancel it?

Comment: Oh dear.. reaching for text expander again... https://smilesoftware.com/textexpander shall abbreviate that to `;iexb`

Answer (score 76):

In general, you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, which will drop you into to the "User switch command" mode with a `--->` prompt.  From here, you can type `i` to interrupt your IEx session, then `c` to reconnect to it; IEx will then state `** (EXIT) interrupted` and return to the state it was in immediately before you got stuck.  This is a feature of Erlang's shell (erl) that was inherited by IEx.

Example of this in action:

```
iex(3)> Enum.each '12345', &(IO.puts(&1"))
...(3)> end
...(3)> )
...(3)> '
...(3)> end
...(3)> ""
...(3)>        <-- Ctrl-G goes here (not shown normally)
User switch command
 --> i
 --> c
** (EXIT) interrupted
iex(3)>
```

Answer (score 11):

My quick and dirty solution is to produce a syntax error with by spamming `"""""""""` (which will be interpreted as heredoc).

In your example:

```
iex(3)> Enum.each '12345', &(IO.puts(&1"))
...(3)> end
...(3)> '
...(3)> end
...(3)> ""
...(3)> """"""""""""""""""""
** (SyntaxError) iex:8: heredoc allows only zero or more whitespace characters followed by a new line after """
```

Comment: `#iex:break` doesn't work for me so this is a great solution :+1